# Two different screen size mobile tooks 320-layout but the alignment get differ from each in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using `five different layouts` for different screen size mobiles such as layout, `layout-320dp`, `layout-480dp`, `layout-600dp`, `layout-720dp`. While testing my app with the mobiles `samsung note3` and `samsung GT-S7582` these two mobiles takes the `layout-320dp` but the alignment is differe from each. Its working for `note-3` but alignment missmatch in `GT-S7582`.If i changed anything for `note-3`  is also affected in `GT-S7582`. Here i have added the layout code and screen shots for your reference. How to make the alignment for these two mobiles as perfect.

layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/appblue"
    android:orientation="vertical">



    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/search_btn"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_blue"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/searchCollege"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/search_college"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fav_btn"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-110dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fav_blue"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myFavourites"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/my_favourites"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/profile_btn"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_blue"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myProfile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/my_profile"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/notification_btn"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-110dp"
        android:background="@drawable/notification_blue"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/notification"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/reminder_btn"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/reminder_blue"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reminder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/reminder"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/logout_btn"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-175dp"
        android:background="@drawable/logout_blue"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/logout"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="1000dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >
    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**screen shot of GT-S7582**

[image: screen shot of GT-S7582]

**screen shot of note-3**

[image: screen shot of note-3]

Answer (score 0):

For making your design responsive make these values folder like for `layout-480dp` make folder `values-480do` , and for others layout respectively `values-600dp` and `values-720dp`.

Then make a resource file name `dimen` in every folder and add in this file your **button height, width , margin top and etc.**

**like this:**

```
<dimen name="button_width">80dp</dimen>
<dimen name="button_height">80dp</dimen>
<dimen name="margin-left">10dp</dimen>
<dimen name="margin-right">100dp</dimen>
<dimen name="margin-top">30dp</dimen>
```

and add in your xml like this:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/search_btn"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
        android:background="@drawable/search_blue"
        android:gravity="center" />
```

then for set the allignment for `layout-320dp` change the `dimen values` in `values-320dp` folder

Try it it works 4 u. Thats the real way in android to make your design reponsive.

Answer (score 0):

The Galaxy S Dous as a ppi of [233](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s_duos_2_s7582-5876.php), while the note 3 has a ppi of [386](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_note_3-5665.php), that's why that is happening. Instead of hardcoding the size of the frame_container, use a dimen instead. Or better yet, instead of using a `LinearLayout` as the parent to your layout, why don't you use a `GridView` or `RecyclerView`? The user will be able to scroll down if there is not enough space on their device